# NSTableView drag freezes dock

Tags: drag-and-drop, nstableview, appkit

When I drag an NSTableView (view based) item over the dock, the dock freezes. I.e. it does the genie effect when entering the Dock area, but then it is just stuck.

I've implemented:

```swift
func tableView(_ tv: NSTableView, pasteboardWriterForRow row: Int)
     -> NSPasteboardWriting?
```

to make the row draggable, it is returning an own NSObject implementing NSPasteboardWriting, nothing special really (declares a string and a custom type).

Also D&D is working just fine within the app. It is just for outside drags, when it starts to fail.

Q: Any idea what I may be doing wrong? :-)

Sample code: https://gist.github.com/helje5/48728983951ab3362af43b967c554475

P.S.: I also have a custom view implementing `NSDraggingSource` itself, and that seems to work just fine.

[image: Demo GIF]

Comment: Please post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/helje5/48728983951ab3362af43b967c554475

Comment: I tried your code but I can't drop. How do you get the genie effect, do you drop on a minimized window?

Comment: I get the genie effect by enabling that in the Preferences/Dock :-) The issue is unrelated to the actual _dropping_ of the dragged item. (you can drag the labels, right?)
You drag the item over the Dock, then the Dock "genies" (increases the icon size at the point where the drag enters the dog), but it sticks there. It feels like the event loop is stuck for some reason. Always repro's for me.
(for now I solved it by not using NSTableView DnD, but by initiating the drag session in the cell view itself.

Comment: Also added a GIF showing the issue I'm talking about. The genie effect should follow the cursor (the genie effect just illustrates the issue well, the drop target selection is also b0rked when this happens)

Comment: Do you mean the Minimize windows using Genie effect popup button or the Magnification check box and slider? I don't see the Genie effect in your GIF.

Comment: Is the item supposed to be droppable outside the app? The freezing of the Dock looks like a bug in the Dock app. Dragging an Automator task over the Dock has the same effect.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes I was referring to the magnification of the Dock icons. This should follow the mouse (but it is not just the effect which is b0rked, you also can't drop).
I'm not sure it is an issue with the Dock, because if I implement the D&D manually in the view being dragged, it works just fine!

Comment: Do you call `tableView.setDraggingSourceOperationMask`?

Comment: Spot on, that fixes it!!! (want to write an answer, or should I self-answer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an item which can't be dropped outside the app is dragged over the Dock then the animation of the Dock freezes. Call

```
func setDraggingSourceOperationMask(_ mask: NSDragOperation, forLocal isLocal: Bool)
```

with `forLocal` is `false` to make the item droppable outside the app.